# Calling the same function twice in a single return statement in Python

Tags: python, recursion

While going through some python codes, I found a program as follows

```
class py_solution:
    def sub_sets(self, sset):
        return self.subsetsRecur([], sorted(sset))

    def subsetsRecur(self, current, sset):
        if sset:
            **return self.subsetsRecur(current, sset[1:]) + self.subsetsRecur(current + [sset[0]], sset[1:])**
        return [current]


print(py_solution().sub_sets([4, 5, 6]))
```

How does the function call work for this function being called twice in the same return statement(highlighted in bold) and what will be the output of the given query?

It would be helpful if a detailed explanation is given.

Comment: What do you think should happen?

Comment: The way to learn these things is to step through it by hand or with a debugger, or try a few small test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program outputs a set of all possible subsets of the given set.
For the given input it will give all subsets of [4, 5, 6] which are:
[[], [6], [5], [5, 6], [4], [4, 6], [4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]

The first defined function is a wrapper function implemented to pass the relevant parameters for the recursion function.

The recursion function has a stop condition, and that's if the given set is empty, and in that case, it returns the current built set of sets. If the set is not empty the recursion function splits returns two sets which are, a set that has the sset[0] element included and the other set doesn't include sset[0] element. In the recursion that builds every possible subset of the given set (every element can be included or not included).

Comment: Thanks, for the answer.Understood the logic but my query here is the return type of [current] is a list so why all the possible values from [current] are enclosed within another list as you have mentioned in the output?

Comment: Thats because the operator + when applied joins the elements together for example [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5] gives [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. In our case we dont want to join all the sets, we want each one seperatly (if we return without the extra [] the return value would be one list). And with the help of [current] we are doing: [[1,2,3]] + [[4,5]] that gives [[1,2,3],[4,5]]. The element that are joined are the lists inside the list.